# Problem with mobile_theme theme switcher module

Tags: 7, theming

I've tried using [mobile_theme](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_theme) to switch to a selected mobile theme when a mobile visitor browses. But using online mobile emulators: mobilephoneemulator.com and transmog.net I found that half of pages get shown as Desktop version pages.

I thought of using [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) but I'll need to use  browser version, operating system to serve mobile content. But it could fail for Googlebot, Bingbot etc, they also need to see my mobile pages.

Is there any alternative auto theme switcher for mobile? I'm on shared hosting and can't use Browscap etc php modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mobile_theme wouldn't work with Drupal cache on. It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. We should use m.example.com for mobile url's for Drupal. I tried many such modules except for ThemeKey but the same problem( since I was using the cache).

I finally wrote my own module. But later found : [simple_mobile_redirect](https://drupal.org/project/simple_mobile_redirect) to be good one but have not tried yet.

Answer (score -1):

For one language site, you can use [Mobile JS Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_js_redirect) module for Drupal 7.

> This is a simple module that adds a JS in the HTML head to perform a redirect from a desktop site URL to a mobile one or the other way around. This is useful when Varnish or any other reverse proxy cache is being used to cache
>   your site and keep a mobile vs desktop redirect working.